# JWPlayer: Start playing video after it loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I need to show a video in a site automatically, but the customer wants it to be shown only after it starts playing. Is this possible?

To explain this better, on document.ready I have the player.swf opening and then it starts playing the video. However, before showing the actual video, there are 2 or 3 seconds of buffering while the video loads and then it starts playing. How can I avoid showing these buffering seconds to the user? This way, when the box that plays the video opens it does with the video starting, with no buffering or loading wheels.

Any ideas?

Comment: To be honest, you might need to explain to your customer that users don't like emptiness. If they wait 2-3 seconds and nothing seems to be happening, they'll just move on to another site that isn't so "slow" because that is the perception. Having some kind of buffering indicator at least indicates to the user that something is happening. Additionally, it would help if you provided some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to better help you because I can't tell if your video is opening in a lightbox or the box is on the page somewhere.

Comment: thanks... it's an adult site though, not sure if i can post it here... He knows that people don't like to be waiting, that's why he wants the loading to happen in the background... This is something like a video popping up for advertisement, there is already some content, but he wants it to pop right when the video is playing... The video is just in a simple <div>, executed by jwplayer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `jwplayer().play();`

After you setup player using `jwplayer.setup()` , just make a call to `jwplayer().play();` and video should start playing.

See [the documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference/) for more.

Comment: But video will not play until it is loaded, Also to make a call to jwplayer().play();  in setup 

you need to call it in onReady() function...http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/......
but i think ....autostart : true .... is a better option

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29240/autostart-and-mute/

Answer (score 3):

if you have not found answer yet than this might help

It is quite easy in setup just include 'autostart : true'
I am using jwplayer 6 
[Autostart](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29240/autostart-and-mute/)
[Embedding jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player)

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      autostart: true,
      mute: true
    });
</script>
```

And to avoid buffering in user end, you can have your own loader (buffering image) on Buffering...using

onBuffer() API in jwplayer .... so that user will understand that video is being loaded

**onBuffer(callback)**
*Fired when the player enters the BUFFERING state. Event attributes:
oldstate (String): the state the player moved from. Can be IDLE, PLAYING or PAUSED.*

[Jwplayer onBuffer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seating the **bufferlength** flashvar to 0?
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options

It's flash only and won't work with the html5 player.

Answer (score 0):

This is the comment issue i found when use JW flash player.

I found one solution of it.

Open "player.xml" file in your wordpress plugin or JW Flash player config

Set the smoothing flashvar to false. Set the bufferlength flashvar to 1.